# Firefox renders SVG rotated patterns with lines along the seams

Tags: firefox, svg

So the goal here is to have a 2 color diagonal hatch pattern that can be rotated to arbitrary angles dynamically (fyi it's being applied to a D3 map w/zooming).

I found the "SVG Pattern Contains Whitespace Between Repetitions in Firefox(1) question, however the solution is not very flexible rotation-wise and I couldn't make it work with the 2 colors bars.

[Here's a jsfiddle test case.](http://jsfiddle.net/rk6nc/9/). The first 4 are my technique rotated differently. The last one is an attempt to adapt follow the previously mentioned answer's advice.

Chrome renders it fine(2) (as does Safari and IE).

[But Firefox has these nasty lines where it tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OdMT.jpg), but only when the pattern is rotated to something other than 90deg increments.

Any ideas?

Here's the contents of the Jsfiddle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xml:space="preserve" width="925" height="810" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="hatch" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:16" />
            <line x1="13" y1="0" x2="13" y2="10" style="stroke:gray; stroke-width:16" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="hatch45" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(5 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <line x1="-2" y1="-2" x2="-2" y2="12" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:16" overflow="visible" />
            <line x1="12" y1="-2" x2="12" y2="12" style="stroke:gray; stroke-width:16" overflow="visible" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="hatch80" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(80 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:16" />
            <line x1="13" y1="0" x2="13" y2="10" style="stroke:gray; stroke-width:16" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="hatch90" width="10" height="10" patternTransform="rotate(90 0 0)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:16" />
            <line x1="13" y1="0" x2="13" y2="10" style="stroke:gray; stroke-width:16" />
        </pattern>
        <pattern x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="line-fill" viewBox="0 0 20 20" overflow="visible" patternTransform="rotate(80 0 0)">
            <g stroke-width="20">
                <line x1="0" y1="-10" x2="0" y2="30" stroke="black" />
                <line x1="20" y1="-10" x2="20" y2="30" stroke="gray" />
            </g>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <rect style="fill:url(#hatch45);" x="10" y="0" width="200" height="130" />
        <rect style="fill:url(#hatch80);" x="10" y="150" width="200" height="130" />
        <rect style="fill:url(#hatch90);" x="10" y="300" width="200" height="130" />
        <rect style="fill:url(#hatch);" x="10" y="450" width="200" height="130" />
        <rect style="fill:url(#line-fill);" x="10" y="600" width="200" height="130" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

1: stackoverflow.com/questions/19391071/svg-pattern-contains-whitespace-between-repetitions-in-firefox

2: imgur.com/c8SxdGG

Comment: What version/OS do you have? Your jsfiddle looks fine on my Fx 30.0/Win7.

Comment: Arch and OSX Mavericks with Firefox 30.0. I just tried it on a few Windows VMs, and you're right it does seem to be a unix only problem. I did manage to get it [working with a polygon pattern](http://jsfiddle.net/rk6nc/13/), but still no luck rotating it with patternTransform.

Comment: I can confirm the same bug. Filing with Mozilla now.